# Multiple jquery slider

Tags: jquery, drupal-7, scroll, slider

I'm a novice web designer and have just managed to create my first website using Drupal. On one of the pages I have multiple jquery sliders with buttons to allow the user to scroll through the images. The sliders work fine and scrolls through automatically if left alone, however clicking the buttons on one slider to scroll the images also makes all the other sliders on the page scroll through their images as well.

Each sliders buttons also navigate to their correct images for example clicking on the 2nd button on the 1st slider will scroll to the 2nd image on the 1st slider, but it will also scroll every other slider to its 2nd image.

You can see the problem on my website at:
http://carlingeneralbuilders.co.uk/?q=gallery

The slider is taken from a free drupal theme: bluemasters.

This is the jquery code for the slider:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
    $(".paging").show();
    $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

    //1.Get size of images, 2.how many there are, 3.then determine the size of the image reel.
    var imageWidth = $(".window").width();
    var imageSum = $(".image_reel img").size();
    //var imageSum = $(".image_reel").map(function() {
    //return($(this).find("img").length)
    //}).get();
    var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

    //Adjust the image reel to its new size
    $(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

    //Paging + Slider Function
    rotate = function(){    
        var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
        var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

        $(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
        $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)

        // Code for caption that pops up for each individual image
        //$(".desc").stop(true,true).slideUp('slow');

        //$(".desc").eq( $('.paging a.active').attr("rel") - 1 ).slideDown("slow"); 

        //Slider Animation
        $(".image_reel").animate({ 
            left: -image_reelPosition
        }, 500 ); 


    }; 

    //Rotation + Timing Event
    rotateSwitch = function(){  
    $(".desc").eq( $('.paging a.active').attr("rel") - 1 ).slideDown("slow");   
        play = setInterval(function(){ //Set timer - this will repeat itself every 3 seconds
            $active = $('.paging a.active').next();
            if ( $active.length === 0) { //If paging reaches the end...
                $active = $('.paging a:first'); //go back to first
            }
            rotate(); //Trigger the paging and slider function
        }, 10000); //Timer speed in milliseconds (3 seconds)    

    };

    rotateSwitch(); //Run function on launch

 //On Click
    $(".paging a").click(function() {    
        $active = $(this); //Activate the clicked paging
        //Reset Timer
        clearInterval(play); //Stop the rotation
        rotate(); //Trigger rotation immediately
        rotateSwitch(); // Resume rotation
        return false; //Prevent browser jump to link anchor
    });    

});
```

Then I implement each slider through a block on drupal with the following html and php code:

```
<div class="main_view">
<div class="window">
<div class="image_reel">
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/61.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/62.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/63.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/64.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/65.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
<img src="<?php print base_path() . drupal_get_path('theme', 'bluemasters') . '/images/jobs/bathroom/66.jpeg'; ?>"></a>
</div>
<div class="descriptions">
<div class="desc" style="display: none;">Bathroom</div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="paging">
<a rel="1" href="#">61</a>
<a rel="2" href="#">62</a>
<a rel="3" href="#">63</a>
<a rel="4" href="#">64</a>
<a rel="5" href="#">65</a>
<a rel="6" href="#">66</a>
</div>
</div>
```

I think the problem is to do with the fact that the jquery file is only called once for all the sliders and so as a result all the images are grouped together in some way, however I am a real novice and my knowledge of html coding, jquery and drupal is very limited currently.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this, while rotating, you are selecting your elements with class. It return all image sliders and you are animating all of them in this code segment:

```
//return all elements with class image_reel and performs animate for all of them
$(".image_reel").animate({ 
   left: -image_reelPosition
}, 500 );
```

You should refactor your function to work with given element. To find the correct image slider, you should use the following code:

```
$(".paging a").click(function() {    
    //this is the correct image slider.
    $selectedImageSlider = $(this).parent().siblings(".window").find('.image_reel');

    //your codes

});
```

While calling the rotate function, you can pass this image slider as argument to rotate function, and make necessary operations on the slider.

---

ps: You can check this [link](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_id_class.asp) to understand the idea of class and id attributes basically.

Answer (score 0):

and welcome to the exciting world of web development!

I see a closely related problem which I don't think you've mentioned: the number of images is different in each slider, so if you scroll to the right then some of them show nothing at all.

There are probably lots of ways round this. Here's one of them:

You can rewrite it so that it runs in each `<div class="main_view">` separately. I'm assuming each of the sliders is enclosed in one of these elements. You can iterate over the main_views using the `each` method of a jQuery object (not to be confused with the statis `each` method of `$` itself). Then, in each iteration of the loop, instead of doing jQuery searches of the whole document using `$(selector)`, search in the context of the slider using the `find` method, i.e. `currentSlider.find(selector)`. The following sample code is untested:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {    

    //Set Default State of each portfolio piece
    $(".paging").show();
    $(".paging a:first").addClass("active");

    // iterate through the sliders
    $(".main_view").each(function() {
        //0.this is a raw HTML DOM element; convert it to a jQuery object.
        var currentSlider = $(this);
        //1.Get size of images, 2.how many there are, 3.then determine the size of the image reel.
        var imageWidth = currentSlider.find(".window").width();
        var imageSum = currentSlider.find(".image_reel img").size();
        var imageReelWidth = imageWidth * imageSum;

        //Adjust the image reel to its new size
        currentSlider.find(".image_reel").css({'width' : imageReelWidth});

        //Paging + Slider Function
        rotate = function(){    
            var triggerID = $active.attr("rel") - 1; //Get number of times to slide
            var image_reelPosition = triggerID * imageWidth; //Determines the distance the image reel needs to slide

            currentSlider.find(".paging a").removeClass('active'); //Remove all active class
            $active.addClass('active'); //Add active class (the $active is declared in the rotateSwitch function)
            // etc
        };

        rotateSwitch = function(){
            // etc
        };

        rotateSwitch();

        currentSlider.find(".paging a").click(function() {
            // etc
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi David thanks for your reply and explanation, I'm fairly sure I understand what you mean. Have you basically re-wrote the function which builds up the slider so that it repeats it every time it comes across a "main_view" div class? I've been through the code and implemented it however it doesn't seem to have made a difference unfortunately. Are there any other parts of code that would need to be edited?

Comment: Yes. But there's an issue I neglected: variable scoping. You have global variables. In general, this is a Bad Idea. Eg `rotate` is global; but it's redefined in each iteration, so its value is overwritten each time, so only the last iteration matters. `rotateSwitch`, `active` and `play` are also global variables. I haven't thought through what all these global variables might do, but I imagine it'd fail differently than before. Declare the variables _inside_ the loop: `$(".main_view").each(function() { var rotate, rotateSwitch, active, play, currentSlider = $(this); // etc`

Comment: Sorry, it still doesn't appear to be working, have you any other suggestions?

Comment: Just looking at the site now. When I told you to use `currentSlider.find`, I meant for all the parts inside the `each` block with CSS selectors: `$(".image_reel")`, `$(".desc")`, etc. Currently, however, the javascript is crashing halfway through. You've rearranged it so that some code that was inside `rotate` is now outside, where one of its variables is undeclared. Move it back inside `rotate`, use `currentslider` where appropriate, then tell us how it goes. Incidentally, are you using any debugging tools? Firebug for Firefox, or Developer Tools for IE, etc. They're indispensable.

Comment: Hi David, sorry for not getting back to you sooner. I'm afraid that I think my jquery knowledge is way too basic at the moment. Luckily though I have managed to find a way around it for anybody else that has come across the same problem: The Views Nivo Slider (https://drupal.org/project/views_nivo_slider) module allows you to create multiple slideshows on one page and there are some good tutorials on youtube that help you set it up. Thanks anyway David.